# Netsurf-fb Unable to initialise the font system error

Tags: xorg, fonts, browser

When I try run `/usr/bin/netsurf-fb` I get the following error after clicking to place the netsurf browser in my X environment:

```
Unable to initialise the font system
```

Running verbosely (`netsurf-fb -v`) gives the extra information:

```
(0.566807) [INFO netsurf] frontends/framebuffer/font_freetype.c:109 ft_face_requester: Loaded face from /usr/share/netsurf/DejaVuSans.ttf
(0.567405) [INFO netsurf] frontends/framebuffer/font_freetype.c:136 fb_new_face: Could not find font face DejaVuSans.ttf (code 1)
(0.567963) [INFO netsurf] frontends/framebuffer/font_freetype.c:197 fb_font_init: Could not find the default font
```

I have a readonly filesystem in my /usr dir, so I can't move my font files to the location it's looking for by default.

I've tried messing with the FONTCONFIG_FILE param by setting the environment variable (export FONTCONFIG_FILE=/storage/fonts.conf) and messing with paths there but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Netsurf looks at 3 directories for fonts:

- ~/.netsurf/
- $NETSURFRES/
- /usr/share/netsurf/

It's a bit annoying they don't show the traversal of these paths when running in verbose mode but rest assured they are being traversed.

So to solve the problem, I moved my DejaVuSans.ttf file to the /root/.netsurf/ dir and alas, it's fixed now!